# Better dataformat than .mat v7.3 for import from Matlab 2016 to Mathematica 11?

Tags: matlab, binary, wolfram-mathematica, type-conversion

I am trying to import data from Matlab 2016a/2016b-prerelease to Mathematica 11 with local storage

- preferable complete documentation
- expansible to big data so binary; now, 1-100 GBs, but TBs needed later
- to convert from Mathematica 11 to Matlab 2016 - is also a plus if the data format can be a bijection; so understanding to read the data format in Matlab 2016a/b and Mathematica 11
- ...

Data and Quality Assurance

- Full data is x-y plane which has 650 000 x 650 000 points so dimensions are about a square matrix.
- Take any subset of the data etc 6500 x 6500 for your examples.
- Save datafile and .tiff image.

Steps

1. Specify any test -data (presenting a 2D-image), and Specify filenames of .tif and datafile files
2. Quality assurance that you get a figure in .tif
3. Store data in your chosen dataformat
4. Quality assurance that you can reload datafile back into Matlab
5. Import datafile in Mathematica
6. Open/process datafile in Mathematica

### Differential solutions

1. Challenges with Matlab's v7.3

   - follows *HDF5* unconventionally without complete documentation; so you cannot do directly *Attempt 1* below

     - I do not understand how unconventiol the dataformat really is so please propose also a stable method to work with v7.3
   - not sure about binary and expansibility to big data
   - Related: [How to get Matlab data imported with the same dimensions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/9815), [How does import data from matlab into mathematica? or how to import matlab code that can be run in mathematica?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_does_import_data_from_matlab_into_mathematica_or_how_to_import_matlab_code_that_can_be_run_in_mathematica), [MAT-File Level 5 File Format](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000440.shtml), ...
2. Challenges of automatic approaches

   - I think not suitable because I want local storage, etc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861642/is-there-a-way-to-import-the-results-or-data-from-matlab-to-mathematica-automati).
3. Matlab's v7 .mat deprecated against v7.3
4. Matlab's v5 and v4 .mat - I think deprecated against v7.3

### My attempts of Work flow for Diff Condition (1)

Some specification: specify datafile as .mat file of v7.3

Attempt 1

- Matlab

  ```
  # Specify test data here
  time=0:0.001:1; potential=sin(time); C = spectrogram(potential); C=reshape(C,1,[]); C=nthroot( abs( C(1,1:1001) ), 1); hFig=figure(); hax=axes(hFig); imagesc(time,potential,C);

  filename=fullfile('/home/masi/Images/test'); 
  filenameMat=fullfile('/home/masi/Images/test.mat');
  export_fig(filename, '-tif', '-q101', '-a1', '-m1', '-RGB', '-nofontswap', '-nocrop', '-transparent', '-dpng', hax);
  save(filenameMat,'time', 'potential', 'C', '-v7.3');
  ```
- Mathematica where #1-2 both succeed with import of many variables

  ```
  (* http://mathgis.blogspot.fi/2010/09/tips-import-matlab-mat-files.html *)
  (* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10589/9815 *)

  (* #1 Succeeds; select specific data sets *)
  mma = Import["~/Images/test.mat", {"HDF5", "Datasets", "/time"}];

  (* #2 Succeeds: Out {"/C", "/potential", "/time"} *)
  mma = Import["~/Images/test.mat", {"HDF5", "Datasets"}];

  (* Output: {{1.}, {1.5}, {2.}} *)
  ```
- Output: steps (1-4) succeeds but import of datafile (step 5) fails in Mathematica 11, see the error message above.

Reading the data in Mathematica where `Flatten` is used to remove one set of braces because one set too much

```
(* https://stackoverflow.com/a/16834090/54964 *)
SetDirectory["Desktop"]
a = Import["m.mat"] ;
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97252/9815 *)
a=Partition[Flatten[a], 5000]

(* Output fails: {} *)
```

### Studying agentp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351308/54964)

He is using simply a square matrix. 
I have the data in three variables: `time`, `potential` and `C`, fitting `imagesc()`'s parameters.

1. Do square matrix of the vectors *time* m x 1 and *potential* n x 1. How can you apply the vector *C* in the square matrix *A*? I do not understand the mathematics here sufficiently to answer the question myself.

   ```
   # time's dimensions m x 1
   # (potential')'s dimensions 1 x n
   time=0:0.001:1; potential=sin(time); A = time' * potential;
   # Output: A is m x n matrix, which is as as expected. 

   # C is vector 1 x m here. 
   C = spectrogram(potential); C=reshape(C,1,[]); C=nthroot( abs( C(1,1:1001) ), 1);
   ```
2. How can you convert the square matrix *A(C)* back to those three variables? - - *A(C)* is about the square matrix where the vector *C* has been applied on the square matrix *A*. I do not understand the mathematics behind it to create the result.
3. How can you keep those pieces of data separate as one binary? - - This may not possible but I want to understand the standards currently.

Matlab: 2016a, 2016b prerelease
Mathematica: 11
OS: Debian 8.5
Related: [Is there a way to import the results or data from Matlab to Mathematica automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861642/is-there-a-way-to-import-the-results-or-data-from-matlab-to-mathematica-automati)

Comment: approach 2 obviously requires knowing the dimensions so you can partition (or `ArrayReshape` appropriately,  (of course one approach to the problem is to write the dimensions to the file)

Comment: Not sure about a general method to get data from matlab to mathematica, but as you are transferring images, have you considered storing them as images?

Comment: "MAT-File 7.3,based on HDF5, but with undocumented special conventions. "  seems like you should not count on it for portability. Personally i would use a raw binary byte stream

Comment: @agentp Can you use binary HDF5 which follows documented conventions? I do not know if there exist anything like that.

Comment: "Importing" to Mathematica (or MATLAB) usually refers to loading the data into memory.  Do you have the terabytes of RAM required for this, since you want to handle terabytes of data?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, no problem with terabytes of memory. No problem with Ram.

Comment: The easy way to transfer data from MATLAB to Mathematica is [MATLink](http://matlink.org/).  I don't know if it works for matrices with more than 2 billion elements as I don't have the memory to test that.  Note that that's 2 billion elements, not 2 GB of RAM.  MATLink also uses intermediate in-memory storage.  But then that's no worse than intermedia on-disk storage if RAM is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an example of raw binary file exchange from matlab to mathematica:

matlab:

```
mat = [ pi 2*pi 3*pi ; 1 sqrt(2)  sqrt(3)  ]
f=fopen('out.bin','w')
fwrite(f,size(mat))
fwrite(f,mat,'double')
... # repeat for however many matrices we need to write
fwrite(f,size(mat2))
fwrite(f,mat2,'double')
...
fclose(f)
```

mathematica:

```
f = OpenRead["out.bin",   BinaryFormat -> True];
size = BinaryReadList[f, "Integer8", 2];
mat = Transpose@ArrayReshape[
         BinaryReadList[f, "Real64",Times@@size],
         Reverse@size];
(* repeat as needed to read multiple matrices *)
Close[f];
MatrixForm@mat
```

> [image]

note the `Reverse` and `Transpose` are needed because matlab writes the data in in column major order. You could alternately do `fwrite(f,transpose(mat),'double')` when you write.

note also this assumes a square array. If you wanted to handle multidimensional arrays you'd also need to write `length(size)` to the file and so on.

for completeness, go back like this:

```
f = OpenWrite["out.bin",  BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[f, Dimensions[mat], "Integer8"];
BinaryWrite[f, Transpose[mat], "Real64"];
Close[f]
```

..

```
f=fopen('out.bin','r')
sz=transpose(fread(f,2))
mat=fread(f,sz,'double')
fclose(f)
```

Comment: Please, see the body. I can now make the square matrix but I cannot apply the vector `C` (required for `imagesc()`) in the square matrix. I do not understand the mathematics behind `C` of `imagesc()`. How to proceed?

Comment: you can write multiple matrices one after the other, just repeat the 2 `fwrite` calls for each matrix. The other part of your question doesn't seem to relate to saving data, maybe post that as a new question.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I am just thinking you can store efficiently the data of `imagesc()`. I do not want to spread the data too much if it can be done with a single matrix, since I think it should be possible.